# Redirecting Apache Logs to STDOUT

Tags: linux, apache, docker

I have a docker container running an apache server in background (apachectl start &) and i am directing the logs to STDOUT/STDERR via **CustomLog /dev/stdout** and **ErrorLog /dev/stderr** directives.

Now , when i invoke the script containing the apache start command (apachectl start &) , i am unable to view the logs on the **console**.

However , if use **apachectl start -DFOREGROUND** as the command , i can very well see the output on console.

Any idea as to how do we get the logs on console for apache which is running in the background?

Thanks for the help

Comment: how about http://serverfault.com/questions/711168/writing-apache2-logs-to-stdout-stderr?

Comment: @Aif tried the 2nd option but not working in case the apache is running in background

Answer (score 5):

If your container runs a main Bash script, you can add these redirections:

```sh
sudo ln -sf /proc/$$/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/access.log
sudo ln -sf /proc/$$/fd/2 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

It will redirect the Apache output to the current Bash's stdout/stderr. Make sure to (re)start Apache after you create the symlink, otherwise Apache will not see it.

It is fine if Apache runs as a systemd/init.d service. In other words, Apache doesn't need to run within Bash.

For us, the purpose of Docker containers is to run continuous integration tests, so I added the lines to our `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Some background: Each process has its own stdout/stderr. Another instance of Bash will not necessarily be connected to the same stdout/stderr. Similarly, the OP's Apache directive **ErrorLog /dev/stderr** will write it to the syslog or the journal if Apache runs as a service.

Comment: I tried this and the logs showed up when docker logs <podname> -n<namespace> command was run. However, when I tried to access the logs from inside the container, cat /path_to_logs.log, the file did not open, The cursor just blinks and nothing happens

Comment: @mnagdev I suggest to ask a separate question if you need both a readable file and redirection to stdout. I would try with `tail /var/log/apache2/access.log -f & tail /var/log/apache2/error.log -f 2>&1 &` instead of the symbolic links.

Answer (score 1):

You can view those logs using `docker logs container_name -f`. This will show the STDOUT and STDERR output of the container as mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/).